# Flexbox making everything columns in Safari

Tags: css, safari, flexbox

I'm trying to create a two-column layout for a site and I've got everything working fine in Chrome, FireFox and IE10/11, however in Safari, the news pods are columnised, rather than sitting two per line, as they should.

Attached are two images, the top showing what I'm trying to achieve (and what I'm seeing on Chrome/FireFox/IE10 and 11) and the bottom shows what's happening in Safari.

The CSS I'm using to achieve this is as follows:

```
.news__listing {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 3.84615%;
    width: 65.38462%;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
    box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -moz-box-direction: normal;
    box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -moz-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-box-lines: multiple;
    -moz-box-lines: multiple;
    box-lines: multiple;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -moz-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-box-align: start;
    -moz-box-align: start;
    box-align: start;
    -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
    -moz-align-items: flex-start;
    -ms-align-items: flex-start;
    -o-align-items: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start;
    -ms-flex-align: start; }
    .news__listing:last-child {
      margin-right: 0; }
    .news__listing:nth-child(2n) {
      margin-right: 0; }
    .news__listing:nth-child(2n+1) {
      clear: left; }

.news__listing .c-article {
      max-width: 50%;
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -moz-box;
      display: box;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: -moz-flex;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
      -moz-box-orient: vertical;
      box-orient: vertical;
      -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -moz-box-direction: normal;
      box-direction: normal;
      -webkit-flex-direction: column;
      -moz-flex-direction: column;
      flex-direction: column;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
      -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
      -moz-flex-shrink: 0;
      flex-shrink: 0;
      -ms-flex-negative: 0; }
```

Am I doing anything obviously wrong?

[image: Desirable image]
[image: Safari image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so after much experimentation I seem to have found the solution - seems that just setting a `max-width` doesn't cut it, so I've had to explicitly set `width: 50%;` to get everything aligning properly.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32623653/safari-8-flexboxs-justify-content-isnt-working-at-all/32639454#32639454